# Resolving local NodeJS dependencies in a Bazel monorepo

Tags: node.js, bazel

I'm trying to learn how to set up a monorepo with Bazel. [My code is on GitHub](https://github.com/igilham/bazel-example).

I'm using [bazelbuild/rules_nodejs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs) version 0.37 with Bazel 0.29.1-homebrew on Mac OS 10.14.5.

The problem I have is that the `require` of the library module doesn't find the resulting lib when running through the `rollup_bundle` rule in [bazelbuild/rules_nodejs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs).

I assume something in my configuration is wrong but it isn't clear from reading the documentation. Relevant code sections are copied in below but the latest version will always be in the repo.

#### Code and build files

**`/WORKSPACE`**

```
workspace(
    name = "bazel_example",
    managed_directories = {"@npm": ["node_modules"]},
)

# load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "build_bazel_rules_nodejs",
    sha256 = "0d9660cf0894f1fe1e9840818553e0080fbce0851169812d77a70bdb9981c946",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/releases/download/0.37.0/rules_nodejs-0.37.0.tar.gz"],
)

load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "yarn_install")
yarn_install(
    name = 'npm',
    package_json = '//:package.json',
    yarn_lock = '//:yarn.lock',
)

load("@npm//:install_bazel_dependencies.bzl", "install_bazel_dependencies")
install_bazel_dependencies()

# Set up TypeScript toolchain
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_setup_workspace")
ts_setup_workspace()
```

In `/apps/jsapp003`, I have a simple "Hello world" app using a library from the same repo (`/libs/jslib001`).

**`/libs/jslib001/index.js`**

```
module.exports = () => 'Hello world'
```

**`/libs/jslib001/BUILD.bazel`**

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "npm_package")

filegroup(
    name = 'src',
    srcs = [
        'index.js',
    ],
)

npm_package(
    name = 'pkg',
    srcs = [
        'package.json',
    ],
    deps = [
        ':src'
    ],
)
```

**`/apps/jsapp003/index.js`**

```
const jslib001 = require('jslib001')

module.exports = () => {
    console.log(jslib001())
}
```

**`/apps/jsapp003/BUILD.bazel`**

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "npm_package", "nodejs_binary", "rollup_bundle")

filegroup(
    name = 'src',
    srcs = [
        'index.js',
    ],
)

npm_package(
    name = 'pkg',
    srcs = [
        'package.json'
    ],
    deps = [
        ':src',
        '//libs/jslib001:pkg'
    ],
)

nodejs_binary(
    name = 'bin',
    entry_point = ':index.js',
    data = [
        ':pkg'
    ]
)

rollup_bundle(
    name = 'bundle',
    entry_point = ':index.js',
    deps = [
        ':pkg',
    ],
)
```

#### Build command and error message

```
bazel build ...
INFO: Analyzed 12 targets (0 packages loaded, 14 targets configured).
INFO: Found 12 targets...
ERROR: /Users/ian/code/bazel-example/apps/jsapp003/BUILD.bazel:31:1: Bundling JavaScript apps/jsapp003/bund
le_chunks_es2015 [rollup] failed (Exit 1) rollup.sh failed: error executing command bazel-out/host/bin/external/
build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/rollup/rollup.sh --config bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/apps/jsapp003/_bundle
.rollup.conf.js --output.dir ... (remaining 3 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
[!] (commonjs plugin) Error: Could not resolve import 'jslib001' from '/private/var/tmp/ian/17079101
d889bedf61702aa4af25ca27/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/74/execroot/bazel_example/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/apps/jsapp003/bundle.es6/apps/jsapp003/index.js'
Error: Could not resolve import 'jslib001' from '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_ian/17079101d889bedf61702aa4af25ca27/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/74/execroot/bazel_example/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/apps/jsapp003/bundle.es6/apps/jsapp003/index.js'
    at Object.notResolved (/private/var/tmp/_bazel_ian/17079101d889bedf61702aa4af25ca27/execroot/bazel_example/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/apps/jsapp003/_bundle.rollup.conf.js:148:9)
    at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ian/17079101d889bedf61702aa4af25ca27/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/74/execroot/bazel_example/bazel-out/host/bin/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/rollup/rollup.sh.runfiles/build_bazel_rules_nodejs_rollup_deps/node_modules/rollup-plugin-commonjs/src/utils.js:20:68

INFO: Elapsed time: 10.651s, Critical Path: 7.74s
INFO: 4 processes: 4 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: Making the dependencies available at their respective paths, unfortunately, doesn't guarantee that the bundler will find them. The bundler is using the node modules resolution algorithm so it's going to look only in node_modules directories.